How to fix null array in ArrayCollection?
Output

App\Entity\TourPackage {#313 ▼   -id: null   -tour_category:
"cultural_tour"   -price: "3400"   -tour_overview: """
<div>tourPackageImage1</div>
"""   -images:  Doctrine\Common\Collections \ ArrayCollection {#314 ▼
-elements: array:2 [▼
  0 =>  App\Entity \ Images {#630 ▼
    -id: null
    -image_name: null
    -tourPackage:  App\Entity \ TourPackage {#313}
  }
  1 =>  App\Entity \ Images {#438 ▼
    -id: null
    -image_name: "random_image.jpg"
    -tourPackage:  App\Entity \ TourPackage {#313}
  }
]   }   -itinerary:  Doctrine\Common\Collections \ ArrayCollection {#315 ▶} }


TourpackageType
        ->add('images',CollectionType::class,[
            'entry_type' => ImageType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'label' => false,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ])

ImageType
    $builder
        ->add('tour_image_1', FileType::class,[
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false
        ])
        ->add('tour_image_2', FileType::class,[
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false
        ])
        ->add('tour_image_3', FileType::class,[
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false
        ])
    ;

Controller
        $tourPackageImage1 = $request->files->get('tour_package')['images']['__name__']['tour_image_1'];
        $tourPackageImage2 = $request->files->get('tour_package')['images']['__name__']['tour_image_2'];
        $tourPackageImage3 = $request->files->get('tour_package')['images']['__name__']['tour_image_3'];

        $tour_images = [$tourPackageImage1, $tourPackageImage2, $tourPackageImage3];
            $images = new Images();
            $images->setImageName($uploadImage->uploadImage($tourPackageImage1));
            $tourPackage->addImage($images);
 
        dd($tourPackage);

When dd($tourPackage) the first array is null. I even tried to put the condition didn't work. How to fix this issue?
  0 =>  App\Entity \ Images {#630 ▼
    -id: null
    -image_name: null
    -tourPackage:  App\Entity \ TourPackage {#313}
  }
  1 =>  App\Entity \ Images {#438 ▼
    -id: null
    -image_name: "random_image.jpg"
    -tourPackage:  App\Entity \ TourPackage {#313}
  }

If 3 images are uploaded then 1st is null, and 3 images are added after the null array. How to remove null array?

I suggest :
$tourPackageValid = array_filter($tourPackage, function ($item){
    return $item->getImageName() !== null;
});

To keep a record, you need to return true
with an ArrayCollection :
$tourPackageValid = $tourPackage->filter($tourPackage, function($item){
    return $item->getImageName() !== null;
});

For more informations about this :

https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-filter.php
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/stable/index.html

